# RTMP Streaming from ios to server?

Tags: ios, networking, video-streaming, rtmp

Right now, I am using a static `librtmp.a` library to open a RTMP connection between my iphone and server. When the record button is pressed, the camera starts taking input, and on captureoutput, uses `AVAssetWriter`'s in different threads to encode the videos to h264/AAC. The videos are then saved to a specific URL. I'm trying to take these processed frames and send them over my RTMP client using `librtmp`.

```
-(void)writeURL:(NSURL*)segmentURL {
    NSLog(@"Utilities are writing...");
    NSData *segmentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:segmentURL];
    const char* body = [segmentData bytes];

    NSLog(@"%i", [segmentData length]);
    NSLog(@"%s", body);

    RTMPPacket packet = _rtmp->m_write;
    RTMPPacket_Alloc(&packet, [segmentData length]);
    packet.m_headerType = RTMP_PACKET_SIZE_MEDIUM;
    packet.m_packetType = RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_VIDEO;
    packet.m_body = (char*)body;

    RTMPPacket_Dump(&packet);
    RTMP_SendPacket(_rtmp, &packet, TRUE);
    //RTMP_Write(_rtmp, packet.m_body, packet.m_nBodySize);
}
```

crashes everytime on the `RTMPPacket_alloc` call and I'm unsure what to do. Is this the right way to approach sending the data over the network?

**EDIT:**
sample output

```
2013-03-31 22:53:16.163 videoAppPrototype[2567:907] Switching encoders
2013-03-31 22:53:16.179 videoAppPrototype[2567:1703] Encoder switch finished
2013-03-31 22:53:16.220 videoAppPrototype[2567:1703] Upload public.mpeg-4
2013-03-31 22:53:16.223 videoAppPrototype[2567:1703] Utilities are writing...
2013-03-31 22:53:16.230 videoAppPrototype[2567:1703] 339171
DEBUG: RTMP PACKET: packet type: 0x09. channel: 0x00. info 1: 0 info 2: 0. Body size: 0.     body: 0x00
```

**EDIT 2:**
I changed my code to use `RTMP_Write()` instead of `RTMP_SendPacket()`.

New Method:

```
-(void)writeURL:(NSURL*)segmentURL {
NSLog(@"Utilities are writing...");
NSData *segmentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:segmentURL];

NSUInteger len = [segmentData length] / sizeof(unsigned char);
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [segmentData bytes], len);
free(byteData);

NSLog(@"%i", [segmentData length]); 

NSLog(@"First write attempt...");
RTMP_Write(_rtmp, (char *)byteData, len);
NSLog(@"Successful?");
}
```

Which now crashes at RTMP_Write, as shown in stack trace:
[image: Stack Trace]
If someone has any idea or needs anymore information, lemme know!

Comment: crashlog and stack-trace would be helpful. Did you check if `[segmentData length]` returns something that makes sense?

Comment: updated code and added output

Comment: Now all we are missing is 1st: the crash log and 2nd the stacktrace.

Comment: Ow, and the fact that the body-size is 0 looks very suspicious to me.

Comment: i'm not sure how to print either of those. and i agree, especially because it should be at least 6 digits

Comment: Hello, Can you please help me? I want to play RTMP stream in my App. I am also using librtmp.a but I am facing issues like when I tries to connect to the URL. The App gives bad access. looking forward to your response.

Comment: post a question with code, error logs, and any other information, then send me the link. i can offer what little insight i have to at least get you a connection.